# Linking error when installing Libpca with Armadillo

Tags: makefile, armadillo

I'm trying to install the Libpca library on my OSX El Capitan. 
I have successfully installed the armadillo library for the libpca.

My first problem was that the libpca did not search for include in /usr/local/include folder for the headers. I solved that with CPATH env variable.

Now I still cannot *make* the source, because I get another linking error:

```
   Making all in src/lib
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make  all-am
/bin/sh ../../libtool  --tag=CXX   --mode=link g++ -D_THREAD_SAFE  -O2 -std=c++11 -version-info 2:0:1 -no-undefined  -o libpca.la -rpath /usr/local/lib pca.lo utils.lo  
libtool: link: g++ -dynamiclib  -o .libs/libpca.1.dylib  .libs/pca.o .libs/utils.o    -O2   -install_name  /usr/local/lib/libpca.1.dylib -compatibility_version 3 -current_version 3.0 -Wl,-single_module
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_wrapper_ddot_", referenced from:
      void arma::syrk<false, false, false>::apply_blas_type<double, arma::Mat<double> >(arma::Mat<double>&, arma::Mat<double> const&, double, double) in pca.o
      stats::utils::compute_column_rms(arma::Mat<double> const&) in utils.o
      void arma::syrk<true, false, false>::apply_blas_type<double, arma::Mat<double> >(arma::Mat<double>&, arma::Mat<double> const&, double, double) in utils.o
  "_wrapper_dgemm_", referenced from:
      void arma::glue_times::apply<double, false, false, false, arma::Mat<double>, arma::Mat<double> >(arma::Mat<double>&, arma::Mat<double> const&, arma::Mat<double> const&, double) in pca.o
      void arma::gemm<false, true, false, false>::apply_blas_type<double, arma::Mat<double>, arma::Mat<double> >(arma::Mat<double>&, arma::Mat<double> const&, arma::Mat<double> const&, double, double) in pca.o
      void arma::glue_times::apply<double, true, false, false, arma::Mat<double>, arma::Mat<double> >(arma::Mat<double>&, arma::Mat<double> const&, arma::Mat<double> const&, double) in utils.o
  "_wrapper_dgemv_", referenced from:
      void arma::glue_times::apply<double, false, false, false, arma::Mat<double>, arma::Mat<double> >(arma::Mat<double>&, arma::Mat<double> const&, arma::Mat<double> const&, double) in pca.o
      void arma::glue_times::apply<double, true, false, false, arma::Col<double>, arma::Mat<double> >(arma::Mat<double>&, arma::Col<double> const&, arma::Mat<double> const&, double) in pca.o
      void arma::glue_times::apply<double, false, true, false, arma::Row<double>, arma::Mat<double> >(arma::Mat<double>&, arma::Row<double> const&, arma::Mat<double> const&, double) in pca.o
      void arma::glue_times::apply<double, false, true, false, arma::Mat<double>, arma::Mat<double> >(arma::Mat<double>&, arma::Mat<double> const&, arma::Mat<double> const&, double) in pca.o
      void arma::glue_times::apply<double, true, false, false, arma::Mat<double>, arma::Mat<double> >(arma::Mat<double>&, arma::Mat<double> const&, arma::Mat<double> const&, double) in utils.o
  "_wrapper_dgetrf_", referenced from:
      double arma::auxlib::det_lapack<double>(arma::Mat<double> const&, bool) in pca.o
  "_wrapper_dsyev_", referenced from:
      bool arma::auxlib::eig_sym<double, arma::Mat<double> >(arma::Col<double>&, arma::Mat<double>&, arma::Base<double, arma::Mat<double> > const&) in pca.o
  "_wrapper_dsyevd_", referenced from:
      bool arma::auxlib::eig_sym_dc<double, arma::Mat<double> >(arma::Col<double>&, arma::Mat<double>&, arma::Base<double, arma::Mat<double> > const&) in pca.o
  "_wrapper_dsyrk_", referenced from:
      void arma::syrk<false, false, false>::apply_blas_type<double, arma::Mat<double> >(arma::Mat<double>&, arma::Mat<double> const&, double, double) in pca.o
      void arma::syrk<true, false, false>::apply_blas_type<double, arma::Mat<double> >(arma::Mat<double>&, arma::Mat<double> const&, double, double) in utils.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[2]: *** [libpca.la] Error 1
make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution:

In the process of the configuration setup, you should add the following parameters:

```
./configure --with-armadillo-libdir='/usr/local/lib' --with-armadillo-incdir='/usr/local/include'
```

Obviously replacing the directory if it is in other place. :)